# How can i invoke a flask endpoint directly from code without using requests

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, tcp

Hey everyone I was tasked a few days ago to create an API style application that listens over a TCP socket for some commands then return some responses mainly success/failures (i know it's dumb but it's the client request) since I have some validation/database stuff I thought of flask directly but I am still stuck on how I am going to invoke the specific endpoints in code directly. here is a small snippet on how I am imagining things would be

```py
from flask import Flask                                                         
import threading

data = 'foo'
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/SomeCommand")
def SomeCommand():
    return { 'Some' : 'Response'}

def flaskThread():
    app.run()


def TcpListenner():
    # logic that listens over tcp socket then invoks the flask app
    # I was thinking about calling app.something() from here
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flaskApp = threading.Thread(target=flaskThread)
    flaskApp.start()
    listenner = threading.Thread(target=TcpListenner)
    listenner.start()
```

any help/ideas would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Do you want to implement it like the socket will listen for different commands, then on each of those commands, there will be different responses?

Comment: And you don't want to make any request to the flask app. Instead the flask app will itself send the response when it gets the commands?

Comment: i basically i want the tcp listener to act as a middleware between the flask app the client

Comment: so the order will be client -> tcp listener -> flaskapp -> tcp listener -> client

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flask_socketio](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-SocketIO/) with which the flask app and socket i.e. tcp listener both start together...
Based on what I've understood, you can do something like this:

That the client will first make a connection to the flask socket.

Then, to send a command to the flask app, the client will send a message to the flask socket with the command in its message.

The flask socket will be listening for messages. So when it receives a message for the specific command, then it emits a response based on that command to the socket which will then be received by the client.

Below is an example code for the flask socket app:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

# other flask APIs can come here and can be called by the client...

def someCommandOneResponse(): # function that sends response to client when flask socket gets command 1
    commandOneResponse = 'Success'
    socketio.emit('message', commandOneResponse)

def someCommandTwoResponse(): # function that sends response to client when flask socket gets command 2
    commandTwoResponse = 'Failure'
    socketio.emit('message', commandTwoResponse)

@socketio.on('message') # when any command is received on the socket from the client
def handleMessage(cmd):
    print('\nCommand Received: ' + cmd + '\n')

    if( cmd == 'SomeCommand1' ): # if the client has sent a message for command 1
        print('Got Some Command 1')
        someCommandOneResponse()
        
    elif( cmd == 'SomeCommand2' ): # if the client has sent a message for command 2
        print('Got Some Command 2')
        someCommandTwoResponse
    
    send(cmd, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=3000) # starts the flask socket (tcp listener) as well as the flask app
```

Comment: hey Zoha, thanks for your response, but I am not trying to interface with WebSockets  i am trying to work with pure low-level TCP sockets.  the  flask_socketio library implements the [socketIO](https://socket.io/) protocol witch is not m case

Comment: Ok Now I understand